# Peculiar behavior with multiple threads/ volatile variables/ conditionals/loops (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, volatile, conditional-statements

Here's a snippet of a web server that I am currently building...

> // ...
>
> ```
> threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
> while (true)
>   if(this.isOn) {
>                 try { // listen for incoming connection
>               this.clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>                    System.err.println("LOG: >> Accept failed! ");
>                    System.exit(1);
>                   }
>       // as soon as a connection is established send the socket
>       // with a handler/processor to the thread pool for execution
>
>                     threadPool.execute(new ClientRequestProcessor(clientSocket));
>         }
> ```
>
> //...

Please note that the isOn variable is a VOLATILE boolean.

If I turn the if into a while... this code works... but as it is it doesn't. May I ask why? From a logical point of view both should work, even if I test that flag in an if... am I missing something?!

[Later edit:] By not working I mean... a browser (e.g. firefox) cannot connect, actually it keeps trying but timesout eventually. Again, if I change that if(isOn) into a while(isOn) it works like a charm.

Any suggestions/ideas are more than welcome!!!

P.S. I need this combo "while(true) if/while(test flag) {...}" because the server can be started/stopped from a GUI... so the top level while(true) is kind of needed so I can recheck whether I am on (and thus listening for connections) or if I am off (and don't really care about incoming connections). Needles to say the event handlers of the GUI can modify the flag at anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is to close the server socket when you want it to stop and start a new one in a new thread when you want it to start. This way you reject new connections and don't consume CPU when its not doing anything.

When isOn == true and you turn it false, it will only not accept connections after the next new connection. (Could be any time later)  Additionally any client new connections will just wait for the accept to be called (or eventually timeout) You can have up to 50 connections waiting to be accepted by default.

When isOn == false, your thread will busy wait, consuming a CPU. I suggest you put in a little delay such as Thread.sleep(250).  This will cut CPU dramatically, but not delay starting again too much.

BTW:

- if you get an exception, you should log/print it out. Otherwise when it fails you won't know why.
- If accept fails, it could be the process is out of files, so you doesn't want it to just die, killing all existing connections.

Comment: I completely agree with what you said. Plus, you are right about the changing the flag to false still guarantees another "listening for a connection" before the server actually "stops serving". But that still doesn't explain the erratic behavior I am getting with the current version of the code! I will probably adopt your solution, but I am still curios why one version works and the other doesn't... when logically both should. The questions wasn't really if there is a better solution (you already proved there is!) but rather why is this java code behaving so awkwardly...

Comment: @Tibi, while(true) if(flag) and while(true) while(flag) should be identical in your case. I suspect your test is not stably reproduceable.

Comment: Again, you might be right on this one as well. Because if I run the if-variant with the debugger and execute the code line by line then it works perfectly... however if I just hit run and leave it alone the if-variant doesn't work! So, indeed I probably can't reproduce the actual state of the machine, thus rendering any attempt to understand this awkward behavior futile. Either way, thank you for the prompt responses... your (initial) refactoring/redesign proposition has already been implemented and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the while(true) and then if(this.isOn) the while loop has no way of stopping.  What happens when the isOn flag is turned to false.  The while loop never stops because it is essentially made to be infinite.  Plug in an else statement to make it break and it should work as expected.

If you take out the if statement and just make it while(this.isOn) then when the isOn flag is turned to false the loop ends. No infinite loop.

Those are my thoughts at first glance ...

Comment: Hi! Did you read my P.S.?  When I say turn the if into a while I mean >>>> while(true) while(this.isOn) {...}  << and it works like this... as in the connection is successfully established!

Comment: he doesn't want to exit the loop, just spin around the while(true) waiting for the if to become true. The unexpected behaviour is that if(isOn) never becomes true and so no attempt is made to accept() but if instead he has while(isOn) it does.

Comment: You are partially correct djna. The debugger in eclipse says that the flag does indeed become true. And at some point sends that new handler to the thread pool. But for some reason it doesn't work. However if I change that if into a while it miraculously works (without any other modification anywhere in the code)!

Comment: Sorry, I misread/misunderstood the question.  I did not realize that busy waiting was the expected behavior.

Comment: @ AAB  No problem... I agree it's not elegant too loop infinitely waiting for the GUI to modify a flag in the model... but I was shocked at the actual behavior of the threads so I didn't go further with implementing the rest of the functionality because I was intrigued!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be based on your tight loop there. Is it possible you have multiple instances of the program running on your server? The if(isOn) version will not shut down if you set isOn to false, instead it will simply loop forever burning your CPU.